# Define a function that splits a data sequence, prints each on new line but does not print specific indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have a function I'm trying to define. I have it printing each data sequence onto a new line, however can I have it print/filter out specific indices?

Let's say my data sequence is:

> ABC//DEF//64/G//HI/55/123/JKL

Can I adjust the function to also remove the indices for the numbered data so that it prints:

> ['ABC', '', 'DEF', '', '', '', 'G', '', '', 'HI', '', '', 'JKL']

Perhaps not only ignore the specific indices, but rather replace with a whitespace?

Thanks!

Code below:

```
  def split_lines(lines, delimiter):
  for line in lines:
    tokens = line.split(delimiter)
    print(tokens)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple loops and some accumulation make it possible:

```
def split_em_up(line, sep="/"):
    k = [[]] # start with empty inner list
    for l in line:
        if l == sep:
            k.append([]) # add new inner list
        else:
            k[-1].append(l) # add to last inner list
    
    # fix lists to strings or empty string
    for i,v in enumerate(k):
        v = ''.join(v)  # combine inner list to string
        
        # store empty if string is all numbers, else store v
        k[i] = "" if v.isdigit() else v
    
    return k

with open("yourFile.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("""
ABC//DEF//64/G//HI/55/123/JK2L
QPR/123/ST/U
""")

results = []
with open("yourFile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip() # remove \n and whitespace
        if line.strip(): # avoid empty lines
            results.append(split_em_up(line))

print(*results, sep="\n")
```

to get

```
['ABC', '', 'DEF', '', '', 'G', '', 'HI', '', '', 'JK2L']
['QPR', '', 'ST', 'U']
```

Comment: Thank you! How can this be adjusted so that "t" points to a list of data rows in a txt file? I have that txt file opened and read through variable "lines".

Answer (score 2):

To remove the digits you could use:

```py
import re
def split_lines(lines, delimiter, to_remove='[0-9]'):
  for line in lines:
    tokens = line.split(delimiter)
    tokens = [re.sub(to_remove, '', token) for token in tokens]
    print(tokens)
```

or to remove the ones made only of digits:

```py
import re
def split_lines(lines, delimiter, to_remove='^[0-9]+$'):
  for line in lines:
    tokens = line.split(delimiter)
    tokens = [re.sub(to_remove, '', token) for token in tokens]
    print(tokens)
```

Comment: Thanks! This can work, can we adjust this to remove only digits, but ignore if the digits are paired with letters? Like the difference between "4FF" not being removed and just remove lines with "FF"?

Comment: Hmm, we can do the part about not removing digits paired with letters, but why do you want to remove 'FF' which has no digits?

Comment: Ah so in this scenario - I need to read a series of data rows in a txt file like the sample, however I then need to count the quantity of similar rows and with that, the standalone numbers are irrelevant for the count, but a number with letters like "6FF" is relevant.